# Is org-mode compatible with Plain TeX?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

Being an old timer used to Plain TeX, I'd like to be able to add Plain TeX portions to an `org-mode` file and have them be nicely displayed when exported.  Is it possible to configure org-mode for this to happen?

In defense of using Plain TeX within an `org-mode` file, I would say that Plain TeX is better suited to situations in which one just wants to add a few greek letters and/or formulas, without worriyng about the structure of the document (documentstyle and all that which standard LaTeX usually requires)

Comment: doesn't this just work? http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-fragments.html

Comment: @Tyler, I am happy with the fact that org-mode allows for LaTeX fragments, but my question was mainly about Plain TeX fragments.  As an example, the perfectly good Plain TeX construct `$$\matrix{x & = & y \cr a & = & b}$$` gets org-mode confused as this is not valid in LaTeX.

Comment: It's just a minor personal thing, but I miss being able to use `{\sl these \rm lowkey \bf a lot}`!